# ¿Aplico de manera correcta el algoritmo de selección?

Tags: c

Quisiera que me den su opinión sobre si estoy aplicando de manera correcta el algoritmo de selección, los ejemplos que hay en internet son sólo con listas de números; yo trato de hacerlo con registros.

```
printf("¿desea visualizar los registros? (1 = si || 0 = no): ");
scanf("%i", &band);
if(band==1){
    for(i=0; i<m-1; i++){   ///para las mujeres.
        if(lista[i].edad > promedio_edad){
            ///aplicando el algoritmo para mujeres mayores al promedio.
            ///aquí asignar el menor elemento.
            menor = lista[i];
            for(j=i+1, pos_men=i; j<n; j++){
                if(lista[j].edad < menor.edad){
                    pos_men = j;
                    menor = lista[j];
                }
            } ///FINAL DEL FOR HIJO.
            //if(pos_men != i){
                temp = lista[i];
                lista[i] = lista[pos_men];
                lista[pos_men] = temp;
            //}///FINAL DEL CONDICIONAL DISTINTO DE i;
        }
    }/// FINAL DEL FOR PADRE.

    printf("\n\tIMPRESION EN ORDEN ASCENDENTE\n");
    for(i=0; i<m ; i++){
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", lista[i].nombre);
        printf("Edad: %i\n", lista[i].edad);
        printf("Sexo: %s\n", lista[i].sexo);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

También hago lo mismo para los hombres pero al momento de imprimir, los registros se combinan.

Answer (score 2):

> quisiera que me den su opinión sobre si estoy aplicando de manera correcta el algoritmo de selección

Viendo los comentarios del código **NO**, no estás aplicando los algoritmos de forma correcta

```
    if(lista[i].edad > promedio_edad){
        ///aplicando el algoritmo para mujeres mayores al promedio.
        ///aquí asignar el menor elemento.
        menor = lista[i];
```

Si entra en el `if` es porque la edad del elemento `lista[i]` es **mayor** que el promedio... pero tu vas y lo copias en una variable llamada **menor**... ahí ya estás haciendo algo incongruente.

Una cosa es decir que un elemento es menor que la media y otra es decir que tienes que quedarte con el menor dato. El menor de todos es un valor absoluto así que antes de modificar `menor` tendrías que comprobar la edad de `menor` con la edad de `lista[i]`. Y eso no lo estás haciendo.

> pero al momento de imprimir, los registros se combinan

Lógico y normal... Si todos los datos están mezclados en `lista` y tu únicamente recorres esa colección una vez... los datos estáran mezclados. Si quieres separarlos tendrás que recorrer la lista al menos dos veces: una para separar por sexo y otra para ordenar cada subconjunto.

También podrías crear dos listas separadas, una para hombres y otra para mujeres... pero aparte de que ignoro los requisitos del ejercicio no creo que resolverte todos los problemas te vaya a resolver la papeleta en futuros ejercicios.

> porque me el sitio me decía que no podía pegarlo todo

StackOverflow no es un repositorio de software. Aquí deberías crear preguntas claras y concisas y, a ser posible, con ejemplos mínimos y completos que reproduzcan el problema:

- Lo de mínimo significa que todo lo que no esté directamente relacionado con el problema sobra y no debe estar en la pregunta
- Lo de completo quiere decir que se agradece que el código pueda ser compilado sin problemas simplemente copiándolo de la pregunta... sin hacer cambios adicionales.

Antes de publicar preguntas piensa que al otro lado hay gente como tú que no cobra por responder... así que te agradeceríamos que dejases de lado frases y expresiones que están fuera de lugar (ya me he encargado de borrarlo).

No te vamos a hacer los deberes de clase sino que vamos a intentar resolver las dudas que tengas. Si te hacemos los deberes no aprendes, así de simple. Además que hacerte los deberes así en plan gratis sería como ir a trabajar gratis... no es algo que vaya a funcionar.

Así que como sugerencia final, que en clase no te enseñen nada no es excusa hoy en día. Hay millones de tutoriales y ejemplos en Internet, solo hay que invertir tiempo y esfuerzo en buscarlos y estudiarlos... los atajos en el mundo de la programación no existen.